# Repair power cord with heat shrink tubing without cutting or disconnecting cord

Tags: electrical

Is anyone aware of any heat shrink tubing that is large enough to go over a three-prong plug but will still shrink enough to fit a power cord (size of an outdoor extension cord)?

The cord is damaged and I'd rather not disconnect it or cut it in half if I can avoid it.  But all the tubing I've seen doesn't have a high enough ratio.

Comment: See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any shrink tubing that will shrink that much and still insulate the wires. If the damage to the wires is such that you will need to use shrink tube for an individual wire that might be reason enough to cut through the cord at the damaged point. If the damage is near the male or female end consider lopping off the plug closest to it and replace with a repair plug. I have used a product called "liquid tape". It is sold specifically to be used for re-insulating wire sections. Once the damaged wire is soldered you brush the "tape" on. It dries within a few minutes to a flexible and tough coat. Here's da link:  https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=liquid+tape&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aliquid+tape